# Unable to get htmls using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I used `PyQt5` to get html.

It works fine.

However, I cannot get the second page of the urls.

What should I do?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)
        self.data = []

    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        return True

    def processCurrentPage(self, html):
        url = self.url().toString()
        self.data.append(html)
        if not self.fetchNext():
            QtWidgets.qApp.quit()

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.processCurrentPage)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://www.hello.com/p1', 'https://www.haha.com/p1']
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(urls)
    first_result = webpage.data #empty, why?
    new_urls = [i for i in urls if needToGetHtml(i)]
    webpage.start(new_urls)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Modified:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://www.hello.com/p1', 'https://www.haha.com/p1']
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(urls)
    ret = app.exec_()
    first_result = webpage.data
    new_urls = [i for i in urls if needToGetHtml(i)]
    webpage.start(new_urls)
    ret = app.exec_()
    second_result = webpage.data
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that **Qt is asynchronous** so according to the code you provide the data will be obtained after the eventloop stops:

```
if not self.fetchNext():
    QtWidgets.qApp.quit()
```

So you must obtain the data after `app.exec_()` (you should not use `sys.exit()`):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['https://www.hello.com/p1', 'https://www.haha.com/p1']
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(urls)
    ret = app.exec_()
    print(webpage.data)
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: Thanks, eyllanesc. I changed the code. But PyQt5 is unstable. Sometimes it crashes.

Comment: The code `webpage.start(urls)` will make the program crash, why?

Comment: @Chan How strange, I have tested your code and it works correctly. What are the characteristics of your environment: OS, python version, pyqt5 version, etc? On Linux with PyQt5 5.15 I don't get any problem (I use python 3.8.5 and run it on the console).

Comment: I use Windows 10, python 3.8.5. It is strange that when I print the html obtained, then program does not crash. Does my code have any problems or PyQt5 is unstable?

Comment: @Chan Are you using the console (CMD) to execute the code or some IDE?

Comment: I use Python's IDE, i.e., IDLE.

Comment: @Chan mmm, try running it in the CMD, many IDEs can cause problems.